# Как узнать запущен ли код на heroku или на локальном pc?

Tags: python, heroku

Как узнать запущен ли код на heroku или на локальном pc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше всего это контролировать через переменные окружения. К примеру, задай особую переменную из терминала с помощью Heroku CLI:

```
$ heroku config:set HEROKU=1
```

либо пропиши ее в [Heroku Dashboard](https://dashboard.heroku.com) (подробнее смотри [тут](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#managing-config-vars)). Название переменной не важно, лишь бы уникальное было и понятное тебе. Затем в коде проверяй наличие переменной:

```
import os
is_heroku = os.environ.get('HEROKU', False)
if is_heroku:
    print('running on heroku')
else:
    print('not running on heroku')
```

Answer (score 0):

По url

Если у вас там локальный хост вроде 127.0.0.1, то локально

А если можете перейти по ссылке {ваш домен}.herokuapp.com - то на хероку